# Поворот вершины одновременно по 2-м осям

Tags: java, android, opengl

Изучаю OpenGL ES 2. Прочитал в книге, что для поворота вершин объекта используется такой способ

```
private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, myAngle, 1f, 0f, 0f);
```

Я создаю треугольник с координатами x,y,z (-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (0, 1, 1).
Если я в каждом кадре увеличиваю переменную myAngle, то треугольник, который я рисую будет вращаться вокруг оси X. (как поверхность зонтика, который держат в руке и поворачивают вокруг основания ручки).

Но я хочу усложнить движение треугольного "зонтика".  Он должен вращаться не только вокруг основания ручки, но одновременно вращаться вокруг древка зонтика.
Например, за один поворот зонтика вокруг основания (оси X), он должен сделать 1 поворот вокруг древка зонтика (оси Z)

Подскажите, как этого добиться?

Comment: в rotateM 3 последних параметра и есть вектор/ось вращения XYZ - меняйте координаты от 0 до 1

Comment: С помощью 3-х последних параметров я выбираю вектор, который будет осью вращения. Но это всего ОДНА ось! А мне нужно вращать вершину по двум осям. И эти оси разные!!! Этот вариант не подходит

Comment: кто мешает 2 раза вызвать rotateM?

Comment: Сразу не догадался. Спасибо